# R ggplot2 - Color plot using row as group by color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to qplot a density data. My table looks as:

```
Element1  Element2 Element2 Element4 Element5 Element5
1         1        1        1        1        1 
3         5        9        5        2        1
```

I just want to color by name column but R automatically change my names to Element2.1, Element2.2, Element5.1 Elemenet5.2 when I use read.table.

My code:

```
 dataT <- read.table("file.csv", header=T, sep="\t")
 dataT.long = melt.data.frame(data=dataT)
 qplot(value, color=variable, data=dataT.long, geom='density', xlim='0.8')+
 guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE, keywidth = 0.5, keyheight = 0.5))
```

Edit:

If I have this table, how to colour by group?

```
Element1  Element2 Element3 Element4 Element5 Element6
Group1    Group2   Group2   Group3   Group4   Group4
1         1        1        1        1        1 
3         5        9        5        2        1
```

Comment: Try `read.table("file.csv", header=T, sep="\t", check.names=F)`.

Comment: @lukeA if I try with check.names=F I obtain "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

Comment: Can we have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your edit, I'm guessing the values in different columns with different names should really be the same column - i.e., both Element5 columns should have the same color. In which case, I would just strip the .x that R appends to the end in order to discriminate the variable names.

```
# Read and melt data
dataT <- read.table("file.csv", header=T, sep="\t")
dataT.long = melt(data=dataT)

# Remove the decimal dot and the numbers behind it
dataT.long$variable = strtrim(dataT.long$variable, 8) # this will delete everything after the 8th character

# So it looks like this:
#    element value
#1  Element1     1
#2  Element1     3
#3  Element2     1
#4  Element2     5
#5  Element2     1
#6  Element2     9
#7  Element4     1
#8  Element4     5
#9  Element5     1
#10 Element5     2
#11 Element5     1
#12 Element5     1

# Plot
qplot(value, color = variable, data = dataT.long, geom = 'density', xlim = '0.8') +
  guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE, keywidth = 0.5, 
                            keyheight = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks jakub. In fact, I solved the problem just adding: data <- read.table("data.csv", header=T, sep="\t", check.names=F, row.names=NULL). I just wanted to have the points from each group with the same color, not to mix them in one. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best ones ;-)